# IDA pro 7.5.2 fails to find python.dll even tho it is in the correct folder?

Tags: ida

Anyone ever have this problem? how can it be fixed? Installed ida pro 7.5.2 the other day in the python folder it has two files named 2 and 3 clearly for python 2 or 3 but its not even finding the dlls.

Comment: Do you have Python installed on your computer? if so which version?remember that if your IDA is not original you will not have this support, so it will be necessary to take dependency actions that you want manually.

Comment: I do not have python installed to my computer as I usually use python in ida and not outside of it (idapython) this version of ida has two folders in the python folder 3 and 2 it is version 7.5.2 and ida python comes with this version

Comment: @PeterRobertson last time I installed IDA and didn't have Python I was told to install Python during setup.

Answer (score 1):

Got it sorted had to install correct python version under windows

Comment: Which was correct version?